# Alternate option of ModernHttpClient for Xamarin .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: xamarin.forms, .net-standard-2.0

I have old project which is in Xamarin.Form v2.5. It is PCL project which is deprecated. I was trying to upgrade but for `ModernHttpClient` doesn't work correctly. It shows that the DLL will not work correctly.

[image]

I have following code which is based on `ModernHttpClient`. Can any body please suggest how to handle this in .Net Standard 2.0 as DLL doesn't add correctly?

```
internal class AuthenticatedHttpClientHandler : NativeMessageHandler
{
    public AuthenticatedHttpClientHandler()
    {
        CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
        {
            var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Please suggest

Comment: You could user regular [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) with [Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit)

Comment: @FabriBertani Thanks. Is there any upgrade available for `ModernHttpClient` which supports .Net Standard 2.0? Or I must go with `HttpClient` with `Refit`?

Comment: If you still want to use ModernHttpClient, you could try the [Alex Rainman ModernHttpClient](https://github.com/alexrainman/ModernHttpClient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can any body please suggest how to handle this in .Net Standard 2.0 as DLL doesn't add correctly?

If you just install `ModernHttpClient` to IOS/Android/UWP,there will no problem.From [official sample](https://github.com/alexrainman/ModernHttpClient),`ModernHttpClient` used in native platform :

[image]

**Solution:**

Removing NuGet installed in Forms Solution,just installed for each native platform,then this warnning will disappear.As follow:
[image]

**Right clik Root solution project -> Manage NuGet Package for solution.. -> choose needed native platform to install ModernHttpClient,not choose forms project option**

Comment: Thanks. I have code of ModernHttpClient in Forms Solution. If I remove from Forms Solution and add it in native platform, how will it work in Forms Solution as class file will need Reference of `ModernHttpClient`. Please guide.

Comment: You can refer to this code.(https://github.com/alexrainman/ModernHttpClient/blob/master/ModernHttpClient/Shared/NativeMessageHandler.cs).I will share it with you if there is specific code later. If the answer is helpful, please remember to mark it.^.^